# XMVECTOR in DirectX

Tags: c++, directx, directxmath

Sorry for the dumb question .... but why this does not work ? To show the problem I wrote this simple code:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <DirectXPackedVector.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace DirectX;
using namespace DirectX::PackedVector;

int main()
{
XMVECTOR c = XMVECTORSet(3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f);

return 0;
}
```

VS answers "error C3861: 'XMVECTORSet': identifier not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `XMVectorSet` instead of `XMVECTORSet`(This function does not exist)

Function definition on [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxmath/nf-directxmath-xmvectorset)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to initialize a vectorized-constant for DirectXMath. `XMVectorSet` is best when the parameters are float variables not literal values.

```
XMVECTOR c = XMVectorSet( 3.f, 3.f, 3.f, .3f );
```

In the case of a literal constant, you are better off using:

```
const XMVECTORF32 c = { 3.f, 3.f, 3.f, 3.f };
```

> clang will want you to write it as: `const XMVECTORF32 c = { { { 3.f, 3.f, 3.f, 3f.f } } };` if you have `-Wmissing-braces` enabled.

Other options (again, not the best for literal values, but better for variables):

```
XMVECTOR c = XMVectorReplicate( 3.f );
```

```
float x = 3.f;
XMVECTOR c = XMVectorReplicatePtr(&x);
```

```
const XMVECTORF32 t = { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f };
XMVECTOR c = XMVectorSplatZ(t);
```

The [DirectXMath Programmer's Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/ovw-xnamath-progguide) is a short read, and it covers a lot of use cases.

> If you are new to DirectXMath, you should consider using the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper types for DirectXMath that is included in *DirectX Tool Kit* for [DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) / [DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chuck. May I ask another question ? Is there a way, always in DirectX, to initialise a vector with a number of elements different from 4 ? Just a curiosity. SimpleMath only ?

Comment: For 2 and 3 vectors, you just leave the unused values 0.